# Improper token has been passed replit.com

Tags: python, discord

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Online!")
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching, name = "!help"))

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I am getting this error on replit when I try to run this script:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 208, in 
bot.run('TOKEN')
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
return future.result()
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 304, in static_login
raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

Comment: Aren't you meant to put the actual token instead of `TOKEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token needs to be replaced with an official bot token from discord, do this by going to discord dev portal and create a new application, after that click add bot, copy the token and paste where you have the word TOKEN

Example:

```
@bot.event
Async def on_ready():
    Print(‘Ready’)

Bot.run(‘2893613847hiu123fy8137gfy341gf’)
```

Comment: Yes, and just to emphasize, do *not* post the actual token anywhere. If you need to ask another StackOverflow question about this bot, then post a fake one or a placeholder in your question. If you share that token, then anyone reading your post can pretend to be your bot.

Comment: Makes sense, lol i just made up a bunch of random characters

Comment: I figured. That comment was more directed at the OP for future reference :)